# Как можно ускорить выполнение цикла for в python?

Tags: python, numpy

Есть вот такой вот цикл, заполняющий мне список:

```
        i = 0
        j = 1
        newArray = []

        for m in range(count):  
            x = ArrayOfByte[i] + (ArrayOfByte[j] * 256)
            i += 2
            j += 2
            newArray.append((x >> swift) & 255)
```

Элементов в конечном списке получается много, на выполнение уходит несколько секунд, что довольно много, потому что мне не один раз приходится обращаться к методу, в котором есть этот цикл. Можно ли его как-то оптимизировать? Возможно ли преобразовать этот цикл в генератор? Где-то читал, что метод **append** довольно медленный, но не знаю какой-либо альтернативы ему. Может, стоит использовать массивы **NumPy** вместо списков?

Comment: А что делает ArrayOfByte, может оно тормозит в основном?

Comment: Вы выделяете часть 16-разрядного слова. В других языках можно интерпретировать массив как содержащий слова, а не байты, и исключить вычисление x и два инкремента, и, кроме того, операции можно неплохо векторизовать с помощью mmx/sse/avx/, получив в результате ускорение в 3-10 раз даже без распараллеливания. Может быть, в Python/Numpy тоже можно что-то подобное сделать?

Comment: @CrazyElf ArrayOfByte - NumPy массив, содержащий в себе большое количество целых чисел. Все числа считываются из файла. Суть цикла в том, что он создает мне новый массив после перерасчета, содержащий в два раза меньше элементов. Считывание всех чисел происходит практически мгновенно; я расставил принты в разных частях кода, так сказать экспериментальным путём выяснил, что дольше всего обрабатывается цикл)

Comment: Ну тут явно напрашивается векторизация `numpy`, т.е. сразу весь массив обработать, но для этого нужно понять, что вы собственно делаете

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подготовка искусственных данных:

```
import numpy as np

count = 1_000_000
swift = 4
ArrayOfByte = np.random.randint(255, size=count*2)
```

Проверим, сколько будет работать обычный питон и сколько он насчитает:

```
%%time

i = 0
j = 1
newArray = []

for m in range(count):  
    x = ArrayOfByte[i] + (ArrayOfByte[j] * 256)
    i += 2
    j += 2
    newArray.append((x >> swift) & 255)
print(sum(newArray))
```

Вывод:

```
118611957
CPU times: user 1.76 s, sys: 0 ns, total: 1.76 s
Wall time: 1.76 s
```

А теперь *векторизованный* код `numpy`:

```
%%time

newArray = ((ArrayOfByte[::2] + (ArrayOfByte[1::2] * 256)) >> swift) & 255
print(newArray.sum())
```

Вывод:

```
118611957
CPU times: user 11 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 11 ms
Wall time: 14.6 ms
```

Сумма чисел получилась та же, т.е. код выполняет одинаковые вычисления. При этом *векторизованный* код выполняется в `100` раз быстрее.

P.S. На более "мелких" типах данных вроде `np.uint8` разница между питоном и `numpy` ещё больше - в 1000 раз. `Numpy` на них работает ещё быстрее, а `Python` ещё медленнее. По умолчанию используется тип `np.int64`.

Comment: Всё работает! Спасибо за помощь :)

Comment: @pythoncoder Только за размером данных следите, в `numpy` целые типы ограничены, нужно следить, чтобы переполнения не было, выбрать тип побольше, там есть из чего выбрать.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду установить параметр `dtype=` для массива? С `numpy` сталкиваюсь впервые, не уверен, что правильно вас понял.

Comment: @pythoncoder Да, именно. Хотя может и так не будет проблем, но имейте в виду. Хотя я посмотрел по умолчанию и так максимальный `np.int64` выставляется

Comment: Хорошо, запомню. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @pythoncoder Впрочем, я попробовал начиная с `np.uint8`, нет проблем, оба кода считают одинаково. Только разница ещё больше по времени, уже в 1000 раз )  `numpy` на более мелких типах работает ещё быстрее, а питон ещё медленнее )

Answer (score 2):

Если `ArrayOfByte` – это действительно массив `uint8`, тогда, чтобы представить его в виде массива `uint16` (а к этому и сводится ваша задача), проще и быстрее будет получить соответствующее представление массива.

```
>>> ArrayOfByte = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 255, 255], dtype='B')
>>> ArrayOfByte
array([  1,   0,   0,   1, 255, 255], dtype=uint8)
>>> ArrayOfByte.view('<u2')
array([    1,   256, 65535], dtype=uint16)
```

Итого

```
(ArrayOfByte.view('<u2') >> swift) & 255
```

Если на входе не массив `uint8` и/или на выходе не `uint16`, нужно будет произвести соответствующие преобразования

```
(ArrayOfByte.astype('B').view('<u2') >> swift).astype('B')
```

Здесь на выходе массив байтов, и необходимость наложения маски `255` отпадает.

Answer (score 0):

Если заранее известно значение count (а из кода следует, что это так) то разумнее сначала создать numpy-массив этого размера

```
newArray=np.empty(count)
```

, а потом в цикле просто заполнять его элементы. Обещают ускорение на порядок.

Comment: Нашел решение с массивами numpy, однако желаемого ускорения они мне не добавили. Изначальный массив создаю так же, как описали вы. В цикле заполняю теперь вот такой строчкой `newArray[m] = ((ArrayOfByte[i] + (ArrayOfByte[j] * 256)) >> swift) & 255`.

Comment: @passant основное время тратится именно на заполнение, именно его нужно делать векторным

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать запустить цикл параллельно

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
def process(i):
    #ваша функция
    
results = Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(process)(i) for i in range(count))
```